# getFactHandle method returns null for any fact in Drools

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, kie

I have the following piece of code:

```
KieSession kSession = JPAKnowledgeService.loadStatefulKnowledgeSession(someId, kieBase, null, env)

for (FactHandle f : kSession.getFactHandles()) {
    Object sessionObject = kSession.getObject(f);
    logger.info(String.format("Fact:  %s", sessionObject.toString()));
}

kSession.insert(someFact);

// Let's loop again to see if our fact is indeed there
for (FactHandle f : kSession.getFactHandles()) {
    Object sessionObject = kSession.getObject(f);
    logger.info(String.format("Fact:  %s", sessionObject.toString()));
}

// Do something else with someFact, insert it into some db

// factHandle is null
FactHandle factHandle = kSession.getFactHandle(someFact);
```

Basically, I am loading my persistent `KieSession`, adding a fact to it, looping through facts to check the newly added fact is indeed there, but when I try to get it back, the `factHandle` object is null. I am trying to use Drools with identity based assertion mode. So my related questions are:

1. Why is my fact handle null? The location of `someFact` in memory may have changed in `Do something else with someFact, insert it into some db` phase, would it have an effect on the issue?
2. How does Drools compare identities? I have a `private long id` filed on my `someFact` object, annotated with `@Id`.
3. I am creating my `KieContainer` and `KieBase` as follows:

```

```
@Bean
public KieServices kieServices() {
    return KieServices.Factory.get();
}

@Bean
public KieContainer kieContainer() throws IOException {

    final KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices().getRepository();

    kieRepository.addKieModule(new KieModule() {
        @Override
        public ReleaseId getReleaseId() {
            return kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
        }
    });

    KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices().newKieFileSystem();
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pmrs = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource[] files = pmrs.getResources("classpath*:com/company/**/rules/*.drl");

    for(Resource file : files) {
        String myString = IOUtils.toString(file.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        kfs.write("src/main/resources/"+ file.getFilename(), myString);
    }

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices().newKieBuilder(kfs);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    return kieServices().newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
}

@Bean
public KieBase kieBase() throws IOException {
    KieBaseConfiguration kieBaseConfiguration = kieServices().newKieBaseConfiguration();
    kieBaseConfiguration.setProperty("assertBehaviour", "equality");
    return KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(kieBaseConfiguration);
}
```

```

If I have to switch to equality based assertion, I have implemented `equals` and `hashCode` methods on my object, but couldn't find a way to define my `KieBase`'s assertion as `EQUALITY`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simply the location of `someFact` in the memory being changed in `Do something else with someFact, insert it into some db`, has an effect, so Drools cannot compare using identity mode.
2. The location in the memory. Not the Javax `@Id` annotation.
3. The following is how you put the engine into equality mode:

   ```
   KieBaseConfiguration kieBaseConfiguration = kieServices().newKieBaseConfiguration();
       kieBaseConfiguration.setOption(EqualityBehaviorOption.EQUALITY);
       return kieContainer().newKieBase(kieBaseConfiguration);
   ```